# Producing a forward/directional vector from just the euler rotation components and position

Tags: math, vector, linear-algebra, spark-ar-studio

I'm currently have quite a lot of trouble producing a forward vector based on my accessible transform components. I'm working within SparkAR, where objects are built around a transform class with position, rotation (euler) and scale, as expected, however it doesn't provide any built in methods for retreiving general information such as the relative forward and up vector of the object, a transform matrix, etc.

This leaves me with the task of trying to put this together myself from the available data. The end result is simply to be able to calculate the angle between the forward vector of 2 objects, which is mapped to a 0-1 range and used as a value of texture blending. The goal is for it to simulate fake dynamic lighting through texture blends based on how similar the local object's forward vector is to the forward vector of the directional light.

I must have read 20+ different StackOverflow results by this point covering similar questions, however I've been unable to get correct results based on my testing using their suggestions, and at this point I feel like I need some more direct feedback to my method before I tear my eyes out.

My current process is as follows:

1) Retrieve euler rotation from the animated joint I want to compare against (it's in radians)

2) Convert radian values to degrees

3) Attempt to convert the euler values to a forward vector using the following calculation sample:

```
x = cos(yaw)cos(pitch)
y = sin(yaw)cos(pitch)
z = sin(pitch)
```

I tried a couple of other variations on that for different axis orders, which didn't provide much of a change at all.

Some small notes before continuing, X is pitch, Y is yaw and Z is roll. Positive Z is towards the screen, positive X is to the right, positive Y is up.

4) Normalise the vector (although it's unnecessary given the results I get).

5) Perform a dot product operation on the vector, against a set direction vector, in this case for testing purposes, I'm simply using (0,0,1).

6) Compare the resulting value against the expected result - incorrect.

---

Within a single 90 degree return, the value retreived from the dot product, which by my understanding should be 1 when facing the same direction, and -1 when facing inverse, oscillates between these two range endpoints between 15-20 times.

Another thing worth noting here, is that I did have to swap the Y and Z components of the calculation to produce a non-0 result, so the current forward vector calculation from euler is as follows:

```
x = cos(yaw)cos(pitch)
y = sin(pitch)
z = sin(yaw)cos(pitch)
```

I'm really not sure where to go about moving on from here to produce the result I'm looking for, as I simply don't understand what about the current calculations are going wrong to begin fixing it.

The passed in vector, pre-dot product at the rotations 0, 90, 180 and 270 are as follows:

```
( 1      , 0, -0.00002)
(-0.44812, 0, -0.89397)
( 1      , 0,  0.00002)
(-0.44812, 0,  0.89397)
```

I can see that the euler angles going into the calculations are definitely correct, so the RadToDeg conversion isn't screwing the input up.

Is the calculation I'm using for trying to produce a forward vector from euler rotations incorrect? Is there something I should be using instead?

Any advice on moving forward with this issue would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. there are 3 euler angles  in 3D you are missing roll (which might corrupt your outcome if nested more transforms...) 2. why not construct or use [4x4 homogenuous transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) most engines have it. From that its just a matter of extracting basis vector in direction you want (simple copy)... in the links there are also examples of how to convert between euler angles and matrix back and forward.